# How to yarn upgrade a package to its latest version disregarding package.json version range?

Tags: package.json, yarnpkg

#### Using Yarn ver 1:

I would like to upgrade `"@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.2.13"` to `"@storybook/addon-actions": "3.4.8"`

I tried `yarn upgrade @storybook/addon-actions --latest --exact` but I can't get rid of a caret in `package.json` version.

How to perform version upgrade to latest version without prefix?

PS:
I also have `.yarnrc` in root projects folder with `save-prefix ""` directive in it.

Answer (score 0):

For `Yarn 2+` add to `.yarnrc.yml`:

```yaml
defaultSemverRangePrefix: ""
```

Read more [here](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc)

---

Please, let me know if it works or not )

Comment: Thanks, but we don't use Yarn2. And I don't think we will soon. And it is old problem and I do not remember what it was for. I think it was just for debugging purposes or some testing.

Comment: @Marecky It works for Yarn2+, so for 3 and 4 and etc )